# Can't Save Product Changes

Tags: product, permissions, file-permissions

I have been having some problems with my Magento 1.9.0 installation which seem to be related to access permissions mainly in the var and media directories.
I have had the host reset the permissions to the default permissions.

When I save a Product I get the error:
"File '/home/user/public_html/var/indexer/4//segments_a4xp' is not readable."

Upon further inspection, that file does not exist.

Can anyone please help me out with this?
Thank you.

Comment: The file path you mentioned is strange. I never seen such path in Magento. Did you install any extension?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by simply copying a file of a similar name in the same directory ('segments_a4dp') and renaming it to the missing file ('segments_a4xp'). Seems to have worked okay so far.